# How do we calculate the probabilty in the following situation?

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 300 in a class, 6 have perfect score on first midterm and 9 have perfect score on second midterm. One person will be chosen randomly from the class. If possible with the information given, find the chance the person has perfect score on both midterm.

I think the chance cannot be calculated because we don't know the people who get perfect on both midterms. But I am not sure if I understood the question.

Comment: I think there is not enough information. You need to know what the probability of scoring perfect on the second exam is given that you scored perfect on the first. I think. Dunno for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be calculated, But consider the following two cases:

- None of the $6$ people who have perfect score on the first midterm are among the $9$ people with perfect score on the second midterm. The desired probability $p$ is zero in this case.
- All $6$ people with perfect score have also perfect score in the second midterm. In this case, the desired probability is $$p=p_{\text{max}}=\frac{\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{300}{1}}$$

So the desired probability can be bounded as follows:$$0\le p\le p_{\text{max}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the number of students with a perfect score on both terms, then:

$$\forall{n\in[0,6]}:P(X=n)=\frac{\binom{300}{n}\cdot\binom{300-n}{6-n}\cdot\binom{300-6}{300-9-n}}{\binom{300}{6}\cdot\binom{300}{9}}$$

And the probability of choosing a student with a perfect score on both terms is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{6}P(X=n)\cdot\frac{n}{300}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{6}\frac{\binom{300}{n}\cdot\binom{300-n}{6-n}\cdot\binom{300-6}{300-9-n}}{\binom{300}{6}\cdot\binom{300}{9}}\cdot\frac{n}{300}=1.94\%$$

Comment: Very hard to follow what it's going on, since your $P(X = N)$ isn't normalized and you are giving the illusion that one can infer the joint probability of two events by just knowing the marginalized probabilities of them.

Comment: @nicola: You're right about $P(X=n)$ not summing up to $1$. I've fixed that now.

Comment: I guess that $P(X = n) = C(6,n)C(294,9-n)/C(300,9)$, which gives the same values of your formula, but reverted: I get $P(X=0) \simeq  0.83$, while your formula says $P(X=6) \simeq 0.83$, which I guess it's wrong (my result agrees with a simulation). But the most important thing is that you never mentioned that you are supposing that getting a perfect score on the first test and on the second are independent events.

Comment: @nicola: I think that the independence of the two is a reasonable assumption to make, if no other information is provided.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. Do you really think that a guy with a perfect score and another guy with a zero score on the first test have the same chance of achieving the perfect score on the second test?

Comment: @nicola: No, but there's no mentioning of any other score in general. For all we know, each one of the other students may have got $99$ score on a $100$ scale... In any case, that's what I'm typically used to see in this type of questions - when no other information provided, assume 'independence of events', 'uniform distribution', etc...

Comment: Ok, if you are really going to do that assumption, just state that the probability of choosing a student with a perfect score on both terms is simply `6/300 * 9/300`. No need of evaluating $P(X=n)$.

Comment: @nicola: Why not?